# Retrieve the total number of shipments for each product on ShippingBo

Tags: php, erp

Is it possible to retrieve the total number of shipments for each product on ShippinBo via API?
I've developed a platform for reordering suppliers, and I'll need this data to implement a new function.
retrieve the total number of shipments for each product on ShippinBo via API

Answer (score 0):

We recommend to created a hook on the Shipment resource:
https://developer.shippingbo.com/docs/api/6fkoxdhf5024p-how-to-configure

For each Shipment created the endpoint configured will be called with the products sent, you can save the data and count

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I've just had a look, I'm having a bit of trouble seeing how I can retrieve the information sent by the webhook from my server. can you give me a little more information?

Comment: If I create a webhook on the productstockvariation class, with the id attribute, pointing to, for example: https://reassorts20.comptoir-utilitaire.com/recuperation_donnee.php 
what code should I put in my recuperation_donnee.php file to obtain the product id that is decremented?

Comment: je suis francais si vous préférez, j'ai vu sur votre profil que vous l'étiez aussi

Comment: If you use ProductStockVariation that because you are on an OMS account or you don't use warehouse slot on your SBO account you have a column product_id, if you use warehouse slots and physical stock you must use SlotStockVariation object and you will find a column product_id too. Then you can filter on reason "Order" to know if an order has been shipped with this product

Comment: Okay, but in terms of code, what should I put in my recuperation_donnee.php file to retrieve this data in a variable?

Comment: i think i only got part of your comment, i have nothing after ":"

Comment: Once you have the body parsed, you just have to get the "product_id", you can do: $parsed_body['object']['product_id'] and make sure $parsed_body['object_class'] is the expected type

Comment: how to analyze/recover the body?

Comment: once you have it, you can save it or print or whatever that allow you to analyze it

Comment: Hello, in spite of my impossible attempts to recover data, could you give me indications on the webhook to create and on the code to implement in my file recuperation_donnee.php so that each time an order passes to the dispatched status I can have the id and the quantity sent for each product of the order?

Comment: Yes you can, but I prefer a webhook on Shipment (https://developer.shippingbo.com/docs/api/6b55a2dd664af-shipment) that is created when the order pass to shipped. When the order is dispatched you cannot make sure the entire order will be sent. Can you show us your code please

Comment: ok I finally made it, thanks for your help! But the id I receive in order_item_id does not correspond to the id of one of my products.

Comment: here is the result I get : {"object_class":"Shipment","object":{"id":55214587,"created_at":"2023-06-22T11:44:24+00:00","updated_at":"2023-06-22T11:44:24+00:00","order_id":69475729,"carrier_name":"La Poste","shipping_method_name":"Lettre simple","carrier_id":13,"shipping_method_id":39,"shipping_ref":"99785965","package_id":99785965,"label_price_cents":null,"label_price_currency":null,"items_shipment_serial_numbers":[],"carrier_barcode":null,"order_items_shipments":[{"order_item_id":132117344,"quantity":1.0,"}} but the product I sent to the id :  26340492

Comment: That is because the order_item_id is not the product but a line of the order, the line can have several products

Comment: How can I retrieve the id of the products sent in this case?

Comment: You can request the order with the order_id and you will retrieve product_id in each order_items

Comment: everything's fine, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: by any chance, would you be able to modify the number of API responses? I'm trying to import all my products via the API, but it only returns 50 each time, even though I have 700.

Comment: No, it's not possible to increase the number of returned records

Comment: How can I ensure that all my products are returned to me in this case? (even if it means doing 50 by 50)

Comment: You must use offset parameter and it should be ok
https://developer.shippingbo.com/docs/api/6288a03f90ffc-get-orders